# Convergence of convex sets in the complementary Hausdorff metric and in the usual Hausdorff metric

Tags: general-topology, geometric-measure-theory, convex-geometry, hausdorff-measure

First of all let me define what is the the complementary Hausdorff distance between  two open sets, I denoted by $d^{H}$ the usual Hausdorff distance in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Let $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ two open subsets of a (large) compact set $B \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, then their complementary Hausdorff distance is defined by :
$$d_{H}(\Omega_1 , \Omega _2) := d^{H}(B \setminus \Omega_1 , B\setminus \Omega_2)$$

Let $\Omega_n$ be bounded open subsets of $\mathbb{R^n}$ such that $\Omega_n$ are convex and converge to a nonempty convex open set  $\Omega$, in the sense of Hausdorff complementary  metric.

I would like to prove that the closure of the sequence $\Omega_n$, denoted $\overline{\Omega_n}$, converges to $\overline{\Omega}$ in the usual Hausdorff metric.

In other words :

($\Omega_n \longrightarrow \Omega $ in the complementary Hausdorff metric )$\Longrightarrow( \overline{\Omega_n} \longrightarrow \overline{\Omega}$ in the usual  Hausdorff metric ).

Comment: Why do you say "if" after "In other words"?

Comment: it's just a topos , thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $B$ is a large closed ball containing all $\Omega_n$.

(1) Since $B-\Omega_n \rightarrow B-\Omega$, if $B(p,r)$ does not
intersect $  B-\Omega$, then $B(p,r/2)$ does not intersect
$B-\Omega_n$.

That is, $p\in \Omega$ implies $p\in \Omega_n $.

**Blaschke's Theorem** implies that if $ \overline{\Omega}_n $
has a limit $C$, then $p\in C$ so that $\Omega \subset C$.

(2) If $\overline{\Omega}=C$, then we are done.

If not, then there is a
point $q\in C$ s.t. open ball $B(q,R)$ does not intersect $ \Omega$.

Since $\Omega$ is open, so it contains some open ball. Here from
convexity of $C$, we have $$C\ \bigcap\ \overline{B(q,R/2)},$$ which contains some closed $\delta$-ball $B_1$.

If $S_n$ is $\varepsilon_n$-net for $B-\Omega_n$, then
$$d_H(S_n,B-\Omega )\leq
d_H(S_n,B-\Omega_n) +
d_H(B-\Omega_n,B-\Omega)<\varepsilon_n+\epsilon_n <\delta$$

That is, there is $z_n\in S_n\ \cap\ B_1$.

Since $B_1$ is compact, then $z_n\rightarrow z\in B_1$. And $ z_n\in
B-\Omega_n \rightarrow z\in B-\Omega$

It is a contradiction.

Comment: Dear @HK Lee thank you for the interest , i have a problem what this mean : $S_n$ is $\varepsilon_n -$ net for $B-\Omega_n$ ?

Comment: A subset $N$ of a metric space $(X,d_X)$ is $\epsilon$-net if any element $x$ in $X$ has $d_X(x,N)\leq \epsilon$.

Comment: Thank you @HK Lee,I am too excited, because I have this conjecture in mind and I believe that it is true your demontration. could better explain to me about the contradiction why ?

Comment: very nice proof , can i ask you one question            
what is your level in math? 
can we have a private discussion ? I do not know if this site offers this

Comment: Yes. I can have a discussion. I am a basic level. I read a part of a convex analysis book and a part of undergraduate metric geometry book.

Comment: to be honest with you I think this deserves a short paper

Comment: I see. I am fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76795/discussion-between-bernstein-and-hk-lee).

Answer (score 0):

May assume that the origin $0$ is inside $\Omega$.

Denote by $d$ the usual distance between sets ($\inf$ of pairwise distances).

1. For any $0<\epsilon <1$ we have 
   $$d((1-\epsilon)\Omega, \Omega^c)= \delta_{\epsilon}>0$$
   so $\Omega_n^c$ will have no points in $(1-\epsilon)\Omega$ for $n$ large enough,
   that is 
   $$\Omega_n \supset (1-\epsilon)\Omega$$
   for $n>n_{\epsilon}$

Let $n> n_{1/2}$, so that $\Omega_n$ contains $\frac{1}{2}\Omega$. Let $B$ be a ball of radius $r$ with center $0$ inside $\frac{1}{2}\Omega$. Assume that 
$\Omega_n$ contains some point $x$ outside of $\Omega$. We'll show that point has to be pretty close to $\Omega$ for $n$ large. Let $x= (1+\epsilon) x_0$, where $x_0$ is on the boundary of $\Omega$. Now $\Omega_n$ contains $x$ and $B$ so it will contain the convex hull $C$ of  $\{x\}\cup B$. The distance from $x_0$ to the complement of $C$ is $\frac{\epsilon}{1+\epsilon} r$ (make a picture in 2D). Therefore, for $n>n'_{\epsilon}$ we have 
$$\Omega_n\subset (1+\epsilon)\Omega$$.

Now we only have to check that as $\epsilon \to 0$
$$(1\pm \epsilon) \bar \Omega\to \bar\Omega$$   in the usual Haausdorff metric (use compactness of $\bar \Omega$).

Comment: Thank you for you interest @orangeskid , the condition thats $\Omega_n^c$ have no point with $(1-\epsilon)\Omega $ i think if the sequences of sets  $\Omega_n$ is increasing. this is not true , what do you think ?

Comment: $\Omega_n^c$ is the complement of $\Omega_n$. If any point from $\Omega_n^c$  lies inside $(1-\epsilon)\Omega$ then its distance to $\Omega^c$ is $\ge \delta_\epsilon$. This can happen only for finitely many $n$. Best to draw a picture.

Comment: yes this what i mean , so your prrof is based on this for$ n\geq n_0 $ , you want to do this  $(1+\epsilon)\Omega \subset  \Omega_n\subset (1+\epsilon)\Omega$ , so you take $\epsilon \rightarrow 0 $ ,one gets $(1\pm \epsilon) \bar \Omega\to \bar\Omega $and where do you use the complementary Haussdorff distance and the consclusion ?

Comment: @Bernstein: it's used twice in the proof. need to go carefully through it.

Comment: excuse me , maybe I do not see the links between $ (1-\epsilon)\Omega \subset \Omega_n\subset (1+\epsilon)\Omega$ and the conclusion 
could you write me more From  this inclusions to the conclusiosn,